# Why does attr_accessor :type return nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, accessor

When overriding the `to_s` method of one of my classes, I'm getting that the field `type` is `nil`. I'm positive that it has a not null value. I have a legacy DB so I'm using `self.inheritance_column = nil` to tell rails not to look for inheritance. This is my class:

```
class BookEntry < ApplicationRecord
  self.inheritance_column = nil
  attr_accessor :type
  self.table_name = 'bookEntries'
  has_many :users_payout_methods, class_name: 'UsersBooks', primary_key: 'id', foreign_key: 'bookId_fk'
  has_many :users, :through => :users_payout_methods

  def to_s
    "type: "+ type + ", genre:" + genre
  end
end
```

Other fields, like `genre` do work properly. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the line

```
attr_accessor :type
```

that basically overrides default Rails getter and setter for a field.

What happens under the hood, is that `attr_accessor` declares two dummy methods:

```
def type
  @type
end

def type=(value)
  @type = value
end
```

Unless you have explicitly set the `@type` instance variable, it’s value is `nil` since the explicit `attr_accessor` broke the magic that reads the value from the database field.

Comment: So I shouldn't ever use `attr_accesor` for fields that are DB columns?

Comment: Unless you want to override the default behaviour, you shouldn’t.